# How many solutions does Riemann's P-symbol describe?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, hypergeometric-function

The [Papperitz-Riemann P-symbol](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Papperitz_equation)
$$ \tag 1
y(z) = P  \left\{ \begin{matrix}
  z_1 & z_2 & z_3 & \; \\
  \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \alpha_3 & z \\
  \beta_1 & \beta_2 & \beta_3 & \;
\end{matrix} \right\}
$$
is used to express the solutions of second order homogeneous complex differential equations of the form
$$ y'' + p(z) y' + q(z) y = 0, $$
with $p$ and $q$ [meromorphic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meromorphic_function) with a finite number of [regular singular points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point).

- How many *different* solutions does the Riemann's P-symbol describe?
- How many (if any) of them describe the same identical function, only represented differently by Laurent expansions around different singular points?

Comment: The Riemann symbol describes the whole set (i.e. a two-dimensional space) of solutions. Different symbols cannot describe the same function, since the coefficients $\alpha,\beta$, roughly speaking, give the leading asymptotic behavior of this function as $z\to z_{1,2,3}$.

Comment: @O.L. what about the analytic extension of a series solution around, say, $z_1$, with order $\alpha_1$? will this be equal to the series solution around $z_2$ in the radius of convergence of the latter? If so, how do I know which coefficients of $z_2$ ($\alpha_2$ or $\beta_2$) will correspond to $\alpha_1$? If not, it seems we have more than two solutions

Comment: Once again, the P-symbol describes the whole *two-dimensional space* of solutions. Any local solution at $z_1$, i.e. any linear combination of the $\alpha_1$- and $\beta_1$-solutions, is a linear combination of $\alpha_2$- and $\beta_2$-solutions at $z_2$.

Comment: @O.L. all right. So this means that we could as well say that the whole two-dimensional space of solutions is completely characterized by specifying $\alpha_1$, $\beta_1$ and $z_1$, while the rest is redundant (but nonetheless useful of course). Is that correct?

Comment: No, the differential equation cannot be determined without the rest. So you have possible leading asymptotics at $z_1$ from $\alpha_1,\beta_1$, but to determine subleading corrections in the series solutions, the rest is needed.

Comment: @O.L. sorry but I'm not getting it. You just said that any linear combination of the $\alpha_1$ and $\beta_1$ solutions is a linear combination of the $\alpha_2$ and $\beta_2$. Doesn't this mean that given the latter solution the first is determined? Or is the knowledge of the $\alpha_1, \beta_1$ needed to find the cofficients giving this linear combination?

Comment: I just said that the coefficients of the series giving, say, $\alpha_1$-solution at $z_1$, will also depend on $\alpha_2$, $\beta_2$ and so on. The point which leads to confusion is maybe that specifying the differential equation with regular singular points determines *all* $\alpha$, $\beta$. In the case of three regular singularities, the converse is also true, so sometimes the differential equation is replaced by its Riemann scheme.

Comment: @O.L. you should turn this into an answer! One last thing, to see if I am unerstanding this: the analytic continuation of the $\alpha_1$-solution at $z_1$ (say $y_{11}$) is *not* generally equal to the $\alpha_2$ or $\beta_2$ solution around $z_2$ (respectively denoted with $y_{21}$ and $y_{22}$) in the radius of convergence of the latter, *but* we know that there are a couple of constants $c_1,c_2$ such that $$y_{11} = c_1 y_{21} + c_2 y_{22}.$$ These constants will generally be dependent on all of the $\alpha_i, \beta_i$ and $z_i$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It could be very helpful to work out the details with an example, but the simplest nontrivial case corresponds to Gauss hypergeometric equation, and it already requires rather cumbersome calculations. The next-to-simplest example (4 regular singularities) corresponds to Heun's equation, and here the explicit expressions for $c_1$, $c_2$ in terms of analogs of $\alpha,\beta$ are simply unknown.

Comment: @O.L. if you manage to sum up this discussione into an answer I'll be glad to accept it. I'm trying to work out the case of the associated Legendre equation, we'll see if I get somewhere :)